# Check Instagram banned username

Tags: vb.net, instagram

How i can check if instagram username is banned? Using vb

I tried to read this url to get the account info
https://www.instagram.com/imopvp/?__a=1
But it just return me a error for no logging in
While I’m logged in using 
https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/accounts/login/

```
Try
Dim web as string = new webclient().downloadstring(“https://www.instagram.com/imopvp/?__a=1”)
Msgbox(web)
Catch ex as exception
Msgbox(ex.message)
End try
```

It just return me a error

And i think this will not work
Do you have any other methods?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the login credentials to you webclient;

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
 client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Comment: Looks like a C# answer to a vb.net question. No problem, just that an inexperienced or inattentive user is going to get all sorts of red squigglies.